# Could someone explain explain to what correspond the moments of a random variable?

Tags: probability

Could someone explain what are (at least the four first) moments ? (normalized moment to be more precise) Let $X$ a r.v.

- So the first moment is the expectation. This will correspond to $\mathbb E[X]$ and is going to be the "barycenter" (in the sense that if $X$ is supported on $[a,b]$ and $\rho(t)$ is the density of the line $[a,b]$ (i.e. $\rho(dt)=\mathbb P_X(dt)$), then the barycenter of the line is $\mathbb E[X]$ (I like to see this in physic term).
- So the second moment is the variance. So, it's going to represent the dispersion of the mass around $\mathbb E[X]$, i.e. $66\%$ of the total mass is going to be concentrate on $[\mathbb E[X]-\sqrt{Var(X)},\mathbb E[X]+\sqrt{Var(X)}]$, but I don't really understand why...

Is my intuition for $\mathbb E[X]$ and $\text{Var}(X)$ correct ? What about the the third and the fourth moments ? (I think of higher dimension it's much more abstract).

Comment: Skewness and kurtosis.

Comment: Your interpretation of variance is wrong.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Ok, thank you, but I don't want the name, but the meaning behind. For the variance I corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first moment is the (arithmetic) *mean*, $\mu:=\Bbb E[X]$. If this is finite, any $a$ satisfies $\Bbb E[X-a]=\mu-a$. So if we want to measure spread around $\mu$, we can't use $\Bbb E[X-\mu]=0$, but we can use the *variance* $\sigma^2=\Bbb E[(X-\mu)^2]$, or better still (so we're working with a quantity that has the same dimensions as $X$ and $\mu$, should $X$ not be dimensionless) the *standard deviation* $\sigma=\sqrt{\Bbb E[(X-\mu)^2]}\ge 0$. (You could also look at the *absolute deviation* $\Bbb E[|X-\mu|]$, but that's usually neither as useful nor as easy to analyse.)

If $\mu,\,\sigma$ exist and are finite, the $z$-score of $X$ is defined as $Z:=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$. This has mean $0$ and variance $1$. [We can prove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Probabilistic_proof) $P(|Z|\ge k)\le k^{-2}$, but there are [theoretical reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Occurrence_and_applications) to have an especial interest in a "Normal distribution", for which a much tighter bound can be obtained, which your numerical example considers.

While $Z,\,Z^2$ must have respective means $0,\,1$, $\Bbb E[Z^3],\,\Bbb E[Z^4]$ are another story. Their values are the *skewness* and *kurtosis* of $X$, and indeed of $aX+b$ for $a>0$ (for the kurtosis we can relax this to $a\ne 0$), including $Z$ itself. These quantities provide additional information about $Z$'s distribution. In particular, they provide ways a distribution can notably fail to be Normal. For a Normal distribution, their respective values are $0$ and $3$, and $\Bbb E[Z^4-3]$ is often called the *excess kurtosis* of $X$. We classify distributions by [whether this is positive, zero or negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis#Excess_kurtosis). Note that $\Bbb E[Z^4-1]$ is the variance of $Z^2$, so the excess kurtosis is at least $-2$. [This can be saturated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution#Properties_of_the_Bernoulli_distribution).

A symmetric distribution (i.e. one for which $P(X\le x)=P(X\ge 2\mu-x)$) has either zero or undefined skewness. When the skewness of an asymmetric distribution is defined but non-zero, the sign of the skewness indicates whether the distribution "leans" to the left or right. But despite a common misconception, [it doesn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Relationship_of_mean_and_median) tell you how the mean compares to the median.

A geometric interpretation of the kurtosis is a little harder. You'll sometimes read people saying it describes how flat the distribution's peak is, but [it's better](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4321753/#S9title) to think of it in terms of the behaviour of the distribution's tails.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For example, how $\sigma $ measure the spread ? what mean for example $\sigma =2$ ? Same for skewness and krtosis, what mean skewness= 1 or kurtoris =2 ? (for example)

Comment: @user659895 $\sigma$ is the [RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) of $X-\mu$. It's much harder to make a similar statement about a given value of skewness. But a kurtosis of $2$ means $Z^2$ has variance $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the geometric interpretation of kurtosis is quite simple: Following J.G.'s notation, let $V = Z^4$, and let $p_V(v)$ denote the pdf of $V$. Then the kurtosis of $X$ is the center of mass (point of balance) of $p_V(v)$.

Now, place a fulcrum on the horizontal axis of the graph of $p_V(v)$ at 3.0: If $p_V(v)$ falls to the right, then kurtosis of $X$ is >3, and the distribution of $X$ is heavier-tailed than the normal distribution.  If it falls to the left, then the kurtosis is <3, and the distribution of $X$ is lighter-tailed than the normal distribution.

Yes, "flatness" as a descriptor of kurtosis is quite silly - kurtosis has nothing to do with that. Just look at the beta(.5,1) distribution: It has kurtosis less than 3.0, and hence is classified as "platykurtic." But it is nowhere near flat-topped.  In fact, it is infinitely peaked.

Nor does large kurtosis have anything to do with "peakedness," or "concentration toward the mean."  Think about it: With kurtosis > 3, why does the pdf of $Z^4$ ($p_V(v)$) fall to the *right* when the fulcrum is placed at 3.0: Is it because of the "peakedness," or concentration near the mean (which translates to large mass where $X$ is near to $\mu$, and hence $Z^4$ is near $0$), or is it due to tail extremity (where $X$ is far from $\mu$, and hence $Z^4$ is large)? The answer is obviously that $p_V(v)$ falls to the right due to tail extremity.

You can make a similar geometric argument for skewness: Consider the pdf of $Z^3$: Its center of mass is the skewness.  Place a fulcrum at $0.0$: If the pdf of $Z^3$ falls to the right, then the distribution of $X$ is positively skewed, meaning that the right tail of the distribution of $X$ is heavier (as measured by combined leverage of cubed deviations from the mean) than the left tail of the distribution of $X$.  The converse description applies for negative skewness.